# Set-Theoretic Probability

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

Consider
$\{B_i | i \in I\}$ be a collection of events where $I$ is an arbitrary
index set. I would like to show that
$$\left(\bigcup_{i \in I} B_i\right)^c = \bigcap_{i \in I} B_i^c.$$

My friend recommended some form of induction on the size of $I$, i.e.
induct on the value $|I| = n.$ I can see how this is trivial for
$n = 1$, and I have sketched out a variation of this proof for $n = 2$.

Consider
$$x \in (B_1 \cup B_2)^c$$
$$\iff x \notin B_1 \cup B_2$$
$$\iff x \notin B_1 \wedge x \notin B_2$$
$$\iff x \in B_1^c \wedge x \in B_2^c$$
$$\iff x \in B_1^c \cap B_2^c.$$

However, I am having some troubles extending this to the $n > 2$ case. Any
recommendation on how to perform this induction? Or would it be better to do
this with a direct proof?

Comment: $I$ is an arbitrary indexing set, so it is not necessarily finite. The idea is the same for any indexing set $I$. Proceed as you did, replacing "$x \notin B_1$ and $x\notin B_2$" with "$x \notin B_i$ for all $i \in I$" and see where you can get

Comment: I recommend not using induction, but thinking about the general case directly the same way you did the $n=2$ case.

Comment: Does my answer below suffice, or do you need further explanation about something?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of induction, rather following a similar argument to what you had, we get:

$$x \in \left(\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i\right)^c \iff x \notin \bigcup_{i \in I}B_i\iff \forall i, x \notin B_i \iff \forall i, x \in B_i^c \iff x \in \bigcap_{i \in I}B_i^c $$

Even if you had an induction proof, I believe this is better because it holds for arbitrary set $I$ rather than simply a countable sets.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: "$x$ is not in all $B_i$" is equivalent to "there is some $i$ such that $x$ is not in $B_i$".